# I have an issue in PHP to check the headers

Tags: php

Im trying to create a dash board in PHP
Im having issues with the variable

The first one works fine but can get the 2nd to work. Says it is down - I know it is up and running

Any ideas?

````
echo "Dashboard as at: " . date("Y-m-d") . "<br>";
echo " " . date("h:i:sa") . "<br>";
##########################
$url = "http://www.google.com.au"; 
$headers = @get_headers($url); 
if($headers && strpos( $headers[0], '200')) { 

    $status = "$url is up";
    $Color = "#00ff00";
    $Title = "$url";
} 
else { 

    $status = "$url is down";
    $Color = "#FF0000";
    $Title = "$url is down";
}
#############################
$url1 = "http://www.yahoo.com"; 
$headers1 = @get_headers($url1); 
if($headers1 && strpos( $headers1[0], '200')) { 

    $status1 = "$url1 is up";
    $Color1 = "#00ff00";
    $Title1 = "$url1";
} 
else { 

    $status1 = "$url1 is down";
    $Color1 = "#FF0000";
    $Title1 = "$url1 is down";
}
#####################
    echo "<br/><br/>";
    echo  "<table border=\"1\">";
    echo  "<th>API PROD Environment</th>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td BGCOLOR=$Color title=$status><a href=$url>$status</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td BGCOLOR=$Color1 title=$status1><a href=$url1>$status1</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";```
````

Answer (score 0):

For your case, the url "http://yahoo.com" will be redirected to a local yahoo server , so actually the headers[0] will return 301 instead of 200 (but actually in this perspective your codes are correct if you regard a redirection as a "down" status in the original url)

Hence relying on headers[0] containing 200 to determine whether the server is up/down can have the problem you encountered , Such as those with redirection.

One of the solutions is to just use headers return (a completely down server (or one which does not exist) will not return anything):

```
<?php
echo "Dashboard as at: " . date("Y-m-d") . "<br>";
echo " " . date("h:i:sa") . "<br>";


$url = "http://www.google.om.au"; 
$headers = @get_headers($url); 
if($headers) { 

    $status = "$url is up";
    $Color = "#00ff00";
    $Title = "$url";
} 
else { 

    $status = "$url is down";
    $Color = "#FF0000";
    $Title = "$url is down";
}


$url1 = "http://yahoo.com"; 
$headers1 = @get_headers($url1); 
if($headers1) { 

    $status1 = "$url1 is up";
    $Color1 = "#00ff00";
    $Title1 = "$url1";
} 
else { 

    $status1 = "$url1 is down";
    $Color1 = "#FF0000";
    $Title1 = "$url1 is down";
}

echo  $status; 
echo "<br>";

echo  $status1; 
echo "<br>";

?>
```